# get distinct values from associative array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an sql query that gathers info and stores them into a variable. From there i use a while loop to add sql query results into the array.

```
    $array = [];
while ($rows = customfunction_fetch_array($res)){
    $array[] = $rows;
}
```

When i print_r the array it looks something like this.

```
Array([0]=> Array ([Fruit]=> apple [Count]=>4 [Season]=>Summer
      [1]=> Array ([Fruit]=> grape [Count]=>1 [Season]=>Fall
      [2]=> Array ([Fruit]=> apple [Count]=>3 [Season]=>Winter
      [3]=> Array ([Fruit]=> orange [Count]=>5 [Season]=>Spring
      [4]=> Array ([Fruit]=> apple [Count]=>45 [Season]=>All
```

What i want to do is loop though my array and display distinct values on a specified key. For example if i wanted to get all distinct values for fruit. After i loop through my current array my new array should look like

```
$newArray[apple,grape,orange]
```

Comment: Use `array_column` to get all the `Fruit` columns, and `array_unique` to get the distinct values.

Comment: Thanks i just wanted to get pointed in the right direction.